# What are the guidelines I must abide by in order to use this code I found on GitHub in my own Chrome Extension?

Tags: licensing, software-use

[Here](https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/assets/js/goSamples.js) is the code. [This](https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/samples/DOMTree.html) too, a large portion of it. I'm not associated with any organization, I'm just trying to create a Chrome Extension that I will post to the Chrome Web Store and expect people to install for their own use. One of the aforementioned links contains another link to [GoJS's licensing agreement](https://gojs.net/2.0.15/license.html). I think the answer to my question is can be found there, but I need help understanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you first link to starts `/* Copyright (C) 1998-2019 by Northwoods Software Corporation. All Rights Reserved. */`, but as [I have noted here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8548/including-copyrighted-specifications-in-an-mit-licensed-project/8552#8552) this is a historical hangover with no modern function save to really complicate the licensing position of content.  It is, however, a harbinger of bigger licensing issues to come.

Turning to the project's [actual licence file](https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/license.html), we find it not only written in HTML, but HTML made by MS Word; both of these are bad signs.  The licence when viewed makes much (worrying) reference to *License Certificates* and *Evaluation Licenses*, and goes on to say that:

> 2.1.4      Except as may otherwise expressly be permitted by this Agreement, and subject to such additional limitations and restrictions as are set forth in this Agreement, Customer may not:
>
> (a)          use, copy, display, publish, or transfer any Licensed Product;
>
> (b)          modify any Licensed Product, or create any derivative work of any Licensed Product;

This is not free software.  I'm guessing it was never intended to be.  It's a commercial company's commercial source, and in a popular modern form of stupidity they have decided to do their development out in the open on a public `git` server.

You cannot lawfully use this content.  Worse, by even reading it in detail you risk opening yourself up to accusations of any similar work you later write being a derivative, and thus unusable.