# Should I get rid of "All rights reserved"?

Tags: license-compatibility, copyright

Almost all my open source files has "All rights reserved" written along the usual "copyright © 2XXX My name" in the first line. I recently heard that, besides being obsolete, this is in contradiction with some permissive licenses, e.g. MIT, that I state in my projects. So, the question is:
Should edit all my code to erase the "All rights reserved" phrase?

EDIT for clarity:
My doubt is if I **MUST** edit existing files, or I can leave them as they are, while obviously not including the ARR phrase in new files.

Comment: There's an extremely complete answer [here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4403/458).  Could I trouble you to read it, and let us know whether it answers your question, and if not, what remains unanswered?

Comment: @MadHatter It was exactly that answer which raised my doubt. I'm convinced to not include the ARR bit in any new file, but I wonder if I MUST edit the existing ones, a time demanding task, or leave them as they are, and perhaps correct them should the occasion appear?

Comment: Thank you, I understand better now.  Note that it saves everyone time if you spend a few lines telling people what research you've done so far, and you're more likely to get a better answer if you do.

Comment: @KennethLaskoski The summary of the other accepted answer is "you don't need to include it, but including the phrase does no harm."